# "Only valid bearer authentication supported" - error 400

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, access-token, bearer-token

```
// Spotify API
func callAlamo(url: String) {
    let headers = ["Authorization" : "---Removed token---"]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        print(response.result)
        print(response.result.value)
    })
}
```

Why does the code give me this error?

> "Only valid bearer authentication supported" - error 400

[image]

I'm new to `Alamofire`, and it is hard to find lots of information on the internet, thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure you need to put `Bearer 1eb21e...` as access token. Also, you shouldn't post any tokens on the internet. 

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I changed it to `let headers = ["Authorization" : "Bearer 1eb21e79f4d041fa8bd76e18385f260f"]` but got `"Invalid access token" (error 401)`

Comment: Well but that fixed your issue. Now get a valid token. Maybe yours is expired or anything.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I created it about 1 or two days ago on the Spotify dashboard, it's the client ID isn't it?

Comment: I don't think so. It looks really short to me. I'm used to *much* longer tokens. Look out for an access token / API token.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I'm looking on the internet right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot about this post, but it was a real struggle for me so I will post my answer for others in the future.

Here is the code I got in the end:

```
public enum RequestResult {
    case success(JSONStandard)
    case failure(Error)
}


public func getAccessToken() {
    // Get new token
    let parameters = ["client_id" : clientID,
                      "client_secret" : clientSecret,
                      "grant_type" : "client_credentials"]

    func getAccessTokenClosure(completion: @escaping (RequestResult) -> ()) {
        Alamofire.request("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
            // Check if response is valid
            if let accessToken = response.result.value as? JSONStandard {
                completion(.success(accessToken))
            } else {
                completion(.failure(_)) // Can fail with a custom error
            }
        })
    }


    getAccessTokenClosure { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let token):
            // Success
        case .failure(_):
            // Failed, could be due to internet issues etc.
        }
    }
}
```

---

**If you still have questions, ask me no matter how long ago this post was!**